# How to format date in Japanese

Tags: flutter, date, date-formatting

I want to display my date in following format.

YYYY年MM月DD日

When I use the following method to format it;

```
DateFormat('dd MMM, yyyy', 'ja').format(bDate);
```

It does not display it the way I want.

What is the format method to get the date the way I want?

Comment: Have a look at [Link](https://github.com/dart-lang/intl/blob/master/lib/date_symbol_data_local.dart#L9349) . I think it might help you

Comment: This did worked  DateFormat('y年M月d日', 'ja').format(bDate) But is there a common way of formatting the date?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
DateFormat.yMMMMEEEEd('ja').format(bDate);
```